# Xbox 360 Kinect mic not working for chat but works as voice recognized

Tags: xbox-360, kinect

My Xbox 360 Kinect is not working for game chat and party chat. It hears me when I say "Xbox" at the dash board but will not work for game chat. I've done the audio test 3 times and still won't work. The game chat option is on and it says it can hear me. Please respond to this ASAP

Answer (score 0):

This is common among Kinect owners, and has happened to me personally numerous times. Unfortunately, there is no "one true solution" to this issue, as Microsoft provides very little support for the Xbox 360 Kinect anymore.

I would recommend you read through the Xbox 360 Live Chat Support website and going through each of the troubleshooting methods, as well as double checking your Xbox's privacy settings and chat settings. Since you are using the Kinect, ensure that you go through the Kinect's audio calibration and audio tuner just to make sure it's not an issue on that end.

Xbox Live 360 Chat Troubleshooting: https://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/xbox-live/troubleshoot-parties-voice-chat#c29f36195f53433cacfffe8b275159aa

If all else fails, you can contact Microsoft about the issue and they will be able to solve it directly: https://support.xbox.com/en-US/contact-us?NavigationPath=/en-US/xbox-360/xbox-live/troubleshoot-parties-voice-chat